# dSPACE ControlDesk error - No free memory available.[0.000]

Tags: matlab, simulink, dspace-ecu

When using a large sampling rate, no data could be measured (displayed yes but not plotted/stored) and I get the following error from the log file:

*ControlDesk NG Platform:   Error   16:19:41    0,0:No free memory available.[0.000] (0xCA,1)*

dSPACE used - RT1104

ControlDesk version - 5.5

Operating System details:

[image]

Comment: Sure increasing the sample rate increases the memory consumption. At some point you will run out of memory. What is the question?

Comment: How can I work around this problem? I need to get the data but I also need a large sampling rate for the quadrature encoder to work properly. Is it referring to RAM memory consumption? Should I increase RAM? I need at least 15kHz sampling rate. Even with 5kHz I get this message

Comment: "Is it referring to RAM memory consumption?" Yes, it is definitely referring to RAM memory, but I am not sure if it's referring to the RAM of your PC system or the 32MB Ram of the DS1104. I guess the later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed coming from the Real-TimePlatform.
The memory depends on the number of measured signals, the raster speed and the dureation trigger length in the ControlDesk measurment configuration. On the hardware, a buffer is created to be able to hold one entire trigger shot, which may fail if it does not fit to the RAM.
Often a long trigger duration is used causing this problem. Then, the soultion is to measure continuously, which the user most of the time wants instead.
See http://www.dspace.com/faq?408

15kHz is quite fast for the ds1104, by the way, try with litte # of measurements if it works.

Regards, the dspace support :)
(I answered just because i found this question randomly, please contact support@dspace.de (or your local dSPACE company) if you need us!